# Deducing Primitive Type from Raw Memory and Class Analyzers

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, metaprogramming, type-deduction

Specs:

Compiler: TDM-GCC 5.1.0
OS: Windows 8.1 64-bit

I've done a very thorough search though the C++ Standard Libraries, did some other research, and even peaked at some inline assembly. But I haven't come to a conclusion, so here goes:

Given my compiler, if I know the address and size of a primitive type, is there any way in C++ (up to C++14) to deduce the type from just this information, as well as looking at the raw data in memory (I'm willing to work with inline assembly as well)?

An example:

If I have the following declared:

```
float x = 1.0f;
int y = 0x3f800000;  //The same raw value in memory as 'x'
```

is there any way, just by looking at the raw contents of these variables, to deduce their type?

If the simple answer is "no", then please let me give you the context of this question, and maybe you can point me in the right direction.

In short, I'm attempting to write a function that can dissect/analyze a class at runtime (to the furthest extent possible, given that the only real metaprogramming C++ has is templates). I want to be able to determine the member objects of a class given an instance of that class. The "type_traits" library doesn't really help me here, and 'sizeof()' and 'alignof()' offer hints, but it's not enough information to deduce the member objects. And 'typeid()' is useless since I'm working with void pointers, except for grabbing the name of the class.

Crossing my fingers that the C++ ABI/RTTI has somewhat decent metaprogramming.

Comment: None of that information exists at runtime.

Comment: If you want something like that (runtime-reflection), you could still define your own types (classes), instead of using native types. ``class Reflectable { uint32_t typeId; Reflectable(uint32_t tId) : typeId(tId) {}; uint32_t getType() const { return typeId; } }; class MyFloat : public Reflectable { MyFloat( float value } : Reflectable(42), value(v) {}; };``

Comment: Different compilers have different (non-standard) support for introspection. My impression is that clang gives you the most, g++ some, and there are at least 2 g++ introspection libraries, and msvc least.

Comment: The "debug info" that can be generated by the compiler can give you that info. You can turn this on without turning off optimizations. Maybe the compiler can give you info about the binary layout of types even without those debug symbols. You would have to start with a known type though, deducing that type from raw memory would be guessing (not impossible, but difficult and error-prone).

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because book/library recommendations are off-topic, "point me in the right direction". Not that I agree that they should be off-topic. But that's how it is.

Comment: I do not think this question is invalid. He is not asking for books - he says he DID research a lot and found nothing.

Comment: I mean, I'm perfectly ok with "no, this information is not provided during runtime". I just thought it'd be nice to get some perspective on this topic, hence "point me in the right direction". If it's violating rules, then I can just edit it out.

Comment: @PaulRich: The information isn't provided during runtime. And with C++03 that was a real problem for automatic garbage collectors such as the Boehm collector (I never used it). However, you can maybe guess better by also considering alignment.

Comment: Yes, but alignment still isn't enough. I can guess exactly one member with alignof(), since if it's anything bigger than 1, i can deduce that this class has at least one member of size equal to this alignment. Alright then, if that's the case, I'll just answer my own question. That's alright, correct?

Comment: Other languages have type hints along with their types. Erlang for example only uses 24 bits of 32 bit integers (or so...) and the other bits give the type.  C++ is more bare-metal and does not add meta info to the memory representation. If you want that during runtime, you have to do it yourself (see my first comment). If you want it for debugging, you would use debug information as provided by compiler/linker.

Comment: @PaulRich `alignof` is a compile-time operation on *types*. It's of no use unless the type is already known.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I see no reason to close this question, I do not think it is off topic. Quite the opposite actually.

Comment: @molbdnilo Not in a template. My class analyzer function is a function template. In this case, I do not know the type

Comment: @PaulRich template types are expanded at compile time, the type is known at compile time, also for function templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer:
No, this information is not provided during runtime. You can, however, make educated guesses, via alignof(), sizeof(), and knowing what range of values are commonly used for types of certain sizes.

Or create your own Reflection API.

Comment: `alignof` and `sizeof` both require you to know the type at compile time.

Comment: @TommyA Not when you're working with templates. My attempt at a class analyzer function is a function template, so in the function I do not know the type.

Comment: you might not know the type, but your compile sure do know the type at compile time, also when using a function template.